# PHP regex dynamic strings

Tags: php, regex

So this is the part of html content from which i am scraping :

```
<div class="sms-separator"></div>
<div class="wallpaper-ads-right">
  <b>Wallpaper:</b> 
     Rayman Legends Game sms<br />
  <b>Categories: </b>
     <a href="/games-desktop-wallpapers.html" title="Games wallpapers"> Games</a>
  <br /><b>
```

What I need is to get the text in place of 'Games' On page refresh it will be like

```
<div class="sms-separator"></div>
 <div class="wallpaper-ads-right">
    <b>Wallpaper:</b> 
      Souya ssss<br />
    <b>Categories: </b>
      <a href="/soutss-tourguides" title="Tour"> Tourist</a><br /><b>
```

Now from the above content I want to scrape " Tourist "

The problem is the a href and title tag before that have dynamic contents, they vary from page to page so how can I put that in the Regular Expression ?

Comment: So in other words, you want the contents of the `href` tag that immediately follows `<b>Categories: </b>`?

Comment: Why not using a real parser for this like DOM? Parsing html with regexpes is [not good for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1515540).

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is [generally looked down upon](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).  There are more robust solutions.  Are you open to these?

Comment: You might need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy

Comment: Without knowing how the values vary nor the specific target (is it the content withni the href/title attribute or the attribute itself) it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: The value of categories is games , i want the test Games to be my scrapped string @TimPietzcker

Comment: I know which *text*  you want in your examples, my question was "What is the *rule* the regex can follow to find it?".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing and processing HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/parsing-and-processing-html-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

This expression will capture the title of the section and the href & title of each link. I left this as a multiline expression to help with readability. The multiline regex does require the `x` ignore whitespace in pattern option

```
<b>[\w\s]+:\s*<\/b>.*?
<a\b(?=\s)
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\stitle=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))
```

[image]

## Expanded

- `<b>[\w\s]+:\s*<\/b>.*?` finds the catagory header and captures the text before the `:`
- `<a\b(?=\s)` match the open anchor tag
- `(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))` collects the href value, note the additional fluff here is to prevent odd edge cases and allows the attribute to appear in any order inside the tag
- `(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\stitle=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))` collects the title value, same fluff as in the href match above

## PHP Code Example:

**Input Text**

```
<div class="sms-separator"></div>
<div class="wallpaper-ads-right">
  <b>Wallpaper:</b> 
     Rayman Legends Game sms<br />
  <b>Categories: </b>
     <a href="/games-desktop-wallpapers.html" title="Games wallpapers"> Games</a>
  <br /><b>
<div class="sms-separator"></div>
 <div class="wallpaper-ads-right">
    <b>Wallpaper:</b> 
      Souya ssss<br />
    <b>Categories: </b>
      <a href="/soutss-tourguides" title="Tour"> Tourist</a><br /><b>
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/<b>([\w\s]+):\s*<\/b>[\s\r\n]*?
<a\b(?=\s)
(?=(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=(\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|[^\'"][^\s>]*))
(?=(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?\stitle=(\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|[^\'"][^\s>]*))/imsx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <b>Categories: </b>
     <a
            [1] => <b>Categories: </b>
      <a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Categories
            [1] => Categories
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "/games-desktop-wallpapers.html"
            [1] => "/soutss-tourguides"
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Games wallpapers"
            [1] => "Tour"
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while ($line = fgets(STDIN))
    if (preg_match('?<a href=".*" title=".*">(.*)</a>?', $line, $match))
        echo $match[1], "\n";
?>
```