# Match first occurence of string

Tags: html, regex, perl

I have a HTML code that needs to remove the  tag content. They are around 30 in number. It is found in various places inside the HTML code like

```
 <A class=tooltiplink href="javascript:void;" style="color:#000000"><img src="images/footnote.jpg" border="0"><SPAN style="margin:0 0 0 0px;"> unwanted info 4:6 </SPAN></A> 
<b>Hello </b>  
<A class=tooltiplink href="javascript:void;" style="color:#000000"><img src="images/footnote.jpg" border="0"><SPAN style="margin:0 0 0 0px;"> unwanted info 4:6 </SPAN>
</A><b>World</b>
<A class=tooltiplink href="javascript:void;" style="color:#000000"><img src="images/footnote.jpg" border="0"><SPAN style="margin:0 0 0 0px;"> unwanted info 4:6 </SPAN></A>
```

Desired output : **Hello World**

When I try to remove the  tag content as  `$_=~s/A(.+)?\/A//gs;` . It also takes up the useful info inside the last  tag. Removing g too has the same effect. How to remove only the  tag content without the first  and last  matching each other and also removing the useful info.

Comment: Do you have some example input and required output?

Comment: I have posted the sample code. I need only Hello and world.

Comment: Some info are needed to give an generic exhaustive answer:1) i assume this is only partial part of a bigger html code, having maybe several case like your sample. 2) how could we define that (which criteria) the </A> to take as delimiter is the one corresponding to your 'first' <A ...>. 3) unwanted info is the one between first peer <A ...> </A> of a block 4) could we assume that the block is ALWAYS on several line or could be in 1 line also (and need correction in this case)

Comment: I want to replace ALL <A></A> peers. Ya its a inside a big HTML code with no new lines in between <A> and </A>. I dont get ur 2nd assumption. @NeronLeVelu

Comment: could you put an sample of your desired output (in request, not comment due to format missing there) from you sample, it's not clear to me of what to keep and what to remove

Comment: I added the output I just want the Hello World inside bold tag @NeronLeVelu

Comment: I have posted the code and output . @chooban

Answer (score 2):

I think that while you could do this with a regex, it's not the best way to go. The like of [TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) and some [XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm) will give you a much more maintainable solution.

Once you've loaded the HTML into a tree structure, the XPath required might be as simple as:

```
my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse_file( "mypage.html");

my @nodes = $tree->find_nodes( '//b' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the regex is greedy, i.e. it matches the longest matching substring (form the very first A to the very last /A). Try the non-greedy version of the + operator:

```
$_=~s/A(.+?)?\/A//gs;
```

or

```
$_=~s/A(.*?)\/A//gs;
```

By the way, where are the <> characters in your regex? Don't you want to find `<A>` rather than just `A` ?

You probably mean

```
$_=~s/\<A\>.*?\<\/A\>//gs;
```

See here: [How can I write a regex which matches non greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy)

Comment: It's not a good idea to parse HTML with regular expressions, as too much can go wrong (e.g. with the above approach you do not find tags with spaces in them). Unless the exercise is meant to be a quick-and-dirty solution to an ad hoc problem, use an HTML parser!

Comment: How to stop it at first substring itself? @JohnB

Comment: Still I get the content inside link. Thanks I will try the HTML parser. But I don't want the content inside <A> . So can HTML parser neglect content inside certain tags? @JohnB