# Regex data match issue

Tags: javascript, regex, match

My original text is (all one line):

```
var _7question = new Array();
_7question[0] = "question 1";
_7question[1] = "question 2";
_7question[2] = "question 3";
_7question[3] = "question 4";
var _7questionText = new Array();
_7questionText[0] = "ans1"
 _7questionText[1] = " ans2";
_7questionText[2] = " ans3";
_7questionText[3] = "this is the last answer";
```

And I'm attempting to strip out _7question[0] = "question 1"; through _7question[3] = "question 4"; using a javascript match expression.

The expression I'm attempting to use is:

```
(/_7question\[.*\] = .*";/g)
```

However, it seems to also grab the questiontext elements as well which I don't want. I tested this before with each element on its own line and it worked perfectly, but upon setting everything to a single line, the expression no longer works.

Comment: ... Why? Anyway, try `.*?`.

Comment: Yep that was it. And because I'm working on a project that requires this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[0-9]+` to match just numbers.

Edit: It seems you want a [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy) match on your `.*`s.

```
_7question\[.*?\] = .*?;
```