# Replace String in XML file

Tags: regex, sed

I try to replace string in XML file with sed, but since its regular expression doesn't support non-greedy expressions, I encounter a problem.

XML Example:

```
<opt>
  <Node active="yes" file="/home/user/random_filename" last_time="17/07/14-00:02:07" time_in_min="5" />
</opt>
```

I want to find the file attribute, which is random string, and replace it with another string.

This command replaces the string, BUT removes the trailing data.

```
sed 's/file=".*"/file="new_file_name"/' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<opt>
   <Node active="yes" file="new_file_name" />
</opt>
```

How should I handle it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex match non greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"[^"]*"` instead of `".*"`:

**Input:**

```
<opt>
  <Node active="yes" file="/home/user/random_filename" last_time="17/07/14-00:02:07" time_in_min="5" />
</opt>
```

**Command:**

```
sed 's/file="[^"]*"/file="new_file_name"/'
```

**Output:**

```
<opt>
  <Node active="yes" file="new_file_name" last_time="17/07/14-00:02:07" time_in_min="5" />
</opt>
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use `sed` but when manipulating xml documents, you might want to consider xslt. It may be an over the top solution to your problem, but it's a great fit for working with xml.

filter.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<!-- The replacement string is passed as a parameter.
     You can have as many param elements as you need. -->
<xsl:param name="NEW_NAME"/>

<!-- Copy all attributes and nodes... -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ...but when you encounter an element with a file attribute,
     replace it with the value passed in the parameter named $NEW_NAME. -->
<xsl:template match="@file">
    <xsl:attribute name="file">
        <xsl:value-of select="$NEW_NAME"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A libxslt example (add as many --stringparam name/value pairs that you need):

```
xsltproc --stringparam NEW_NAME new_file_name filter.xsl file.xml
```

Result:

```
<opt>
    <Node active="yes" file="new_file_name" last_time="17/07/14-00:02:07" time_in_min="5"/>
</opt>
```

Comment: Nice one! I will consider it. I need to change more than one argument and it looks like most convenient way. Thanks.

Comment: The match attribute xpath expression can be made more specific if needed. For example to only change file attributes in Node elements, change `match="@file"` to `match="Node/@file"`. You can also match based on the contents of the file attribute. To change only those that start with '/home/user/' use `match="Node/@file[starts-with(., '/home/user/')]"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/\(.*file="\)[^"]*/\1new_file_name/' file
<opt>
  <Node active="yes" file="new_file_name" last_time="17/07/14-00:02:07" time_in_min="5" />
</opt>
```