# Match the first substring ocurrance in a string that has two such substrings with regex which usually matches the last one by default

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string `"#This`**`is`**`a string (which`**`is`**`neat!)"`

I want from it the sub-strings `"#This"` and `"a string"`.

The Regex `/#(.*) is (.*)/` gives me this:

```
This is a string (which
neat!)
```

What I expected was this:

```
This
a string (which is neat!)
```

Why is it matching the *second* `is` in the regex and how to get the output I actually expected which is by matching the *first* `is`?

```js
var string = "#This is a string (which is neat!)"
var match = string.match(/#(.*) is (.*)/);
alert('1st match: \t' + match[1] + '\n2nd match: \t' + match[2]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's matching the second "is" because the first part of the regular expression is greedy.

That means that `.*` will start out as matching the entire string, then the regex evaluator will start to backtrack by removing a character at a time from the match until it can find a match for the rest of the pattern.

You can make the quantifier non-greedy by adding a question mark after it:

```
/#(.*?) is (.*)/
```

That will make `.*?` starting out as matching zero characters, and then a character at a time is added until the rest of the pattern matches.

Demo:

```js
var string = "#This is a string (which is neat!)"
var match = string.match(/#(.*?) is (.*)/);
alert('1st match: \t' + match[1] + '\n2nd match: \t' + match[2]);
```