# Using regex to match sentences that may include quote marks ""

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall

I've been trying for a few days now to write a regex that will capture sentences that start with a particular string, and end with a dissallowed character (<). This sentence may contain any punctuation (off the top of my head `[]()-,.!?\/`) and most importantly `'` and `"`, however always will end and start with the same thing (<). So my regex is as follows:

```
    "starting string foo (?:[a-zA-z0-9_]|[-,.!?()\[\]\'\"\/]|[\s])+"
```

This works fine, gets all sentences starting with "starting string foo" and ends with the < after. It successfully gets sentences with every piece of punctuation.... except double quotes ("). I don't understand why this is the case when it can easily get single quotes (') and other punctuation eg. slashes and dashes.

for example- of the string

```
     starting string foo Hubble revisits the famous "pillars of creation" with a new lens <
```

it only captures

```
    starting string foo Hubble revisits the famous
```

but strings like

```
     starting string foo Buzz Aldrin's self-portrait during Gemini 12 with the Earth reflecting off his visor, 12 November 1966 [2651x2632] <
```

with all kinds of punctuation (' - [ ,) it captures all that i want-

```
    starting string foo Buzz Aldrin's self-portrait during Gemini 12 with the Earth reflecting off his visor, 12 November 1966 [2651x2632]
```

Comment: Give a sample string, show us what it matches and also what it should or should not match.

Comment: done, edited into post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
/starting string foo (.*)\</
```

Comment: That works, but doesnt seem to stop (just gets the entire rest of the huge string!).

Comment: ok finally got it to work thanks heaps. The final code was "starting string foo [^<]+"

Comment: I think you may actually be looking for non-greedy matching. See here and let me know, I'll modify my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy