# PHP split or explode string on <img> tag

Tags: php, regex, split, html-parsing, explode

i would like to split a string on a  tag into different parts.

```
$string = 'Text <img src="hello.png" /> other text.';
```

The next function doesnt work yet on the right way.

```
$array = preg_split('/<img .*>/i', $string);
```

The output should be

```
array(
    0 => 'Text ',
    1 => '<img src="hello.png" />',
    3 => ' other text.'
)
```

What kind of pattern should i use to get it done?

**EDIT**
What if there are multiple  tags?

```
$string = 'Text <img src="hello.png" > hello <img src="bye.png" /> other text.';
$array = preg_split('/(<img .*>)/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

And the output should be:

```
array (
  0 => 'Text ',
  1 => '<img src="hello.png" />',
  3 => 'hello ',
  4 => '<img src="bye.png" />',
  5 => ' other text.'
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the right path. You have to set the flag [PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE](http://php.net/preg_split) in this way:

```
$array = preg_split('/(<img .*>)/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

With multiple tag edited properly the regex:

```
$string = 'Text <img src="hello.png" > hello <img src="bye.png" /> other text.';
$array = preg_split('/(<img[^>]+\>)/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

This will output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Text "
  [1]=>
  string(22) "<img src="hello.png" >"
  [2]=>
  string(7) " hello "
  [3]=>
  string(21) "<img src="bye.png" />"
  [4]=>
  string(12) " other text."
}
```

Comment: Is this outdated? When I try to echo this code I only see: 'array'

Comment: @twan, how did you used it?

Comment: I already fixed it, was using echo instead of print_r($array) lol.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include non-greedy character (**?**) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899069/4960774) into your pattern as well, to force it to grab the first occurring instance. `'/(<img .*?\/>)/i'`

so your example code will be something like:

```
$string = 'Text <img src="hello.png" /> hello <img src="bye.png" /> other text.';
$array = preg_split('/(<img .*?\/>)/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

var_dump($array);
```

Which result to printing :

```
array(5) {
    [0] =>
    string(5) "Text "
    [1] =>
    string(23) "<img src="hello.png" />"
    [2] =>
    string(7) " hello "
    [3] =>
    string(21) "<img src="bye.png" />"
    [4] =>
    string(12) " other text."
}
```