# This regex doesn't work in c++

Tags: c++, regex

It is supposed to match `"abababab"` since `"ab"` is repeated more than two times consecutively but the code isn't printing any output.
 Is there some other trick in using regex in C++.

I tried with other languages and it works just fine.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

int main(){

  std::string s ("xaxababababaxax");
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex e ("(.+)\1\1+");   

   while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    for (auto x:m) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that it matches `xa` as well..

Comment: Isn't `(.+)` just greedy and matches the whole string? Therefore the `\1` does not make any sense

Comment: Don't use `<bits/...>`, it's not portable and you have no guarantee it will work tomorrow. Also, you may need to upgrade gcc to the latest and greatest 5.x version, earlier ones don't have a working regexp implementation.

Comment: Use a raw string `R"((.+)\1\1+)"` or escape the backslashes `"(.+)\\1\\1+"`

Comment: @Ed, backtracking will make `.+` match successively less until the `\1` matches.  It's a fairly common idiom in regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is your backslashes are escaping the '1''s in your string.  You need to inform std::regex to treat them as '\' 's.    You can do this by using a raw string R"((.+)\1\1+)", or by escaping the slashes, as shown here:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main(){

  std::string s ("xaxababababaxax");
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex e ("(.+)\\1\\1+");

   while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    for (auto x:m) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Which produces the output

```
abababab ab
```

Comment: How do I add a flag to return the minimum string that matches for example `aaaaaa` should match `a` repeated 6 times not `aa` repeated three times?

Comment: Hmm.  I have to admit you're doing stuff with regex's I haven't tried before.  You could try using the "non-greedy-operator" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy , which is '?', and see if that gets the results you want.   Let me know what you find out!

Comment: No problem.  Regex's can be a  pain in the butt, but they are a really worthwhile skill to develop.