# Why my regex doesn't work in c++ but it works with Python?

Tags: python, c++, regex

I am using RegEx to extract substrings in a [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) formula. For example with this formula:

`10 2 / 3 + 7 4`

I use this RegEx to extract substring (I hope it could return {"10", "2", "/", "3", "+", "7", "4"}

`[0-9]+|[\/*+-])\s?`

Firstly, I try it with Python:

```
s = r"([0-9]+|[\/*+-])\s?"

text = "10 2 / 3 + 7 4"

x = re.findall(s,text)

for i in x:
    print(i)
```

And this is the output, as I think it is.

```
10
2
/
3
+
7
4
```

However, when I use the expression in C++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string text = "10 2 / 3 + 7 4"; 
    smatch m;
    regex rgx("([0-9]+|[\/*+-])\s+"); 

    regex_search(text, m, rgx);

    for (auto x : m){
        cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

The compiler return two warnings in 7th line: unknown escape sequence: '/' and '\s' and it return nothing but several spaces.

I want to know what is the problem with my expression when I use it in C++?

Comment: Perhaps you should escape your backslashes. In Python you're using the `r` prefix to support literal backslashes in the string, but you're not doing anything to support them in the C++ version.

Comment: Your Python string `s` is a raw string that doesn't treat '\' as an escape character. You can do something [similar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in C++, or you can escape your '\' by turning them into '\\'.

Comment: Note that you are using a raw string (`r` prefix) in Python, but you are not doing the equivalent in C++ (`R"(...)"`).

Comment: I have tried to escape my backslashes already. Although no warnings are returned, the code returns only 3 spaces as before.

Comment: See [This regex doesn't work in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098881/this-regex-doesnt-work-in-c).

Comment: Note also that [regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) only finds the _first_ match in the string and is not equivalent to `findall`. Looks like you might want to look into [regex_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator) to generate all matches.

Comment: Yes, see [How to match multiple results using std::regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667295/how-to-match-multiple-results-using-stdregex). This and the above explain all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is used as a escape sequence in C++. You have to write `\` as `\\` to pass it to regex engine.

```
    regex rgx("([0-9]+|[\\/*+-])\\s+");
```

Another option is using *raw string literal* (since C++11):

```
    regex rgx(R"(([0-9]+|[\/*+-])\s+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. First, you aren't escaping the `'\'` character in your C++ string equivalent to how you're doing so in Python.

Possible options:

```
regex rgx("([0-9]+|[\\/*+-])\\s+"); // Escaping the \s
regex rgx(R"(([0-9]+|[\/*+-])\s+)");  // Using a raw string literal
```

Second, the behavior of `std::regex_match` isn't exactly analogous to `re.findall`: It only finds the first subsequence that matches the target expression, not all of them.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search):

> In order to examine all matches within the target sequence, std::regex_search may be called in a loop, restarting each time from m[0].second of the previous call. std::regex_iterator offers an easy interface to this iteration.

[std::regex_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator)

Code using the latter could look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string text = "10 2 / 3 + 7 4";
    std::regex rgx("([0-9]+|[\\/*+-])\\s+");

    auto operands_begin = std::sregex_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), rgx);
    auto operands_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for (std::sregex_iterator itr = operands_begin; itr != operands_end; ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << itr->str() << '\n';
    }
}
```

(As a minor note, I've replaced the `<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` with explicit includes and namespace qualifications.)