# How to extract all content between 2 tags using regex?

Tags: php, regex

My goal is to extract ALL texts that match between 2 tags.

ex:

```
some texts
_start_ hello
world
_stop_
some text
_start_ hello
world2
_stop_
some texts
```

I tried with:

```
 _start_(.*)_stop_
```

which of course is bad.

Here is the snippet: 
https://regex101.com/r/rT8vF1/1

As result I expect something like

```
    res[0] = "hello 
 world";
    res[1] = "hello
world2";
```

Comment: Yes it is HTML parsing.  Just *saying* it isn't doesn't make that so.  (Or if you want to split hairs on what "parsing" means, then using regexes here is wrong *for exactly the same reasons* that it is wrong to parse HTML with regexes.)

Comment: Just removed all HTML

Comment: Brilliant!  Now the code in the answers will break when you try to apply them to real-world HTML :-)

Answer (score 4):

The regex is okay so far, but you have to make to make it non-greedy by adding a `?`:

```
_start_(.*?)_stop_
```

Then it will only match until the next occurence of `_stop_`. You have to substitute the `m` modifier by the `s` modifier to have the `.` also match line breaks.

Comment: It is not correct. Who is upvoting it? `.` matches any character but a newline.

Comment: does not work: https://regex101.com/r/rT8vF1/1

Comment: @yarek: See my community wiki answer at the original question.

Comment: Does ;)  [link](https://regex101.com/r/yJ7qF6/1)

Comment: @stribizhev Funny how you complain that it doesn't work because `.` matches any character and then you mark it as duplicate referring to one of your own answers that also uses `.` ;)

Comment: But also explains that it does it **only with the `/s` modifier**. Gaining points for answering millionth duplicate is not what I call integrity.

Comment: @stribizhev works in regexpal.com. You may also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy

Comment: No, you can see it in the regex101 example: `gim`.