# Removing a substring from a string separated by a delimiter, where the substrings are datetime

Tags: php

I have been searching for days for a solution to a code I am trying to create in PHP.

I have this game where the names of the players and guests are updated in a database, every 5 seconds along with the timeframe they have been active in the game, similar to the example below:

```
$players = "Jennifer,2016-02-14 10:41:02|Don,2016-02-14 11:41:02|Scoop,2016-02-14 10:41:02|";
```

I would like to loop through `$players` and remove any name along with the timeframe where it shows that the player has been inactive for 3 minutes, based on the current time.

I really hope that my question is clear enough and that someone out there could point me in the right direction. I would greatly appreciate it.

$game_id=1;
$name='Jennifer';

```
//First I select all of the players in the game
```

$sql = 'SELECT players FROM gamesvalues WHERE game_id=?'; /* Prepare statement */

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);if($stmt === false) {

trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);

}
 /* Bind parameters. TYpes: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */

$stmt->bind_param('i',$game_id);

/* Execute statement */

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($players);

while ($stmt->fetch())

```
 //Next find out if the name "Jennifer" exists or positioned in players list
```

$pos = strpos($players, $name);

if ($pos === false) {

```
echo "The string '$name' was not found in the string '$guests'";
```

} else {

```
//Once the player's position is found,use substr and strpos to seperate the
//player's name and active time from the list
```

$activeplayer= substr($players,$pos, strpos($players, '|'));

```
//Then use explode to find the active time of the player
```

$playertime = explode(",", "$activeplayer");

$lastactive_time=strtotime($playertime[1]);

$current_time = strtotime(date("h:i:sa"));

```
//Since I have a time limit of 3 mins for inactive players to be in game,
//I subtract the last active time of the player from the current time using strotime
//If the time is greater than 3 minutes, I remove the player by using str_replace
```

$timedifference=round(abs($lastactive_time - $current_time) / 60);

if ($timedifference>3)

$newusr=str_replace($activeplayer.'|',"",$players);
}

Comment: any effort on your side?

Comment: Nordenheim is right, show at least your code!

Comment: take a step back and store the data in a useabel format

Comment: Yeah, remake your database. Your format is really messed up.   And @Dagon, whenever I read "take a step back" it makes me remember the skyrim shuffle

Comment: @PhiterFernandes i had to google that, i hate you :-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1y-CCqeRiQ

Comment: @Dagon Not sure what you mean by "store the data in a useabel format. But the user along with their active time are stored in  field called players.

Comment: [db normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) really important if your site growss

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to extract desired values from your *players* fields: you can find the [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) of `,` and `|` and then extract the pieces through [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), or you can [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) string by `|` and then [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) each row by `,`, but the speediest way is to use [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
$pattern = '/([^,]+),([^|]+)\|/';
preg_match_all( $pattern, $players, $matches );
```

By this way, each substring matching pattern `$pattern` is captured in `$matches` array, in which you have the entire pattern at index `[0]`, the first parenthesis group at index `[1]` and the second parenthesis group at index `[2]`.

The above `$pattern` means:

```
(
    [^,]+   One or more characters excluding comma
)
,           Comma (not grouped)
(
    [^|]+   One or more characters excluding vertical bar
)
\|          Vertical bar (not grouped)
```

To match vertical bar, they must be escaped, because regex use unescaped vertical bar as *OR* operator; in the second group it is not escaped due to prepended caret (`^`).

You can obtain identical result using Question mark as [ungreedy modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy), but I chose above syntax for greater clarity.

At this point, you have in `$matches` following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jennifer,2016-02-14 10:41:02|
            [1] => Don,2016-02-14 11:41:02|
            [2] => Scoop,2016-02-14 10:41:02|
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jennifer
            [1] => Don
            [2] => Scoop
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-02-14 10:41:02
            [1] => 2016-02-14 11:41:02
            [2] => 2016-02-14 10:41:02
        )

)
```

and you can process `$matches[2]` to compare values with actual time.

**This regular expression can also help you if you decide to convert actual data in a more suitable database structure.**

---

- Read more about [Regular expression syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: This looks like it could work.  Gonna check it out and post my results.  Sorry I am fairly new to PHP, so I was wasn't sure how to approach it codewise.  This is why I wasn't able to provide an example. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function remove_the_name( $name, $player ){
    $player = explode( "|", $player );
    foreach( $player as $key => $one_player ){
        $players[$key] = explode( ",", $one_player );
    }
    $key = get_the_key_of_uname( $name, $players );
    $str = "";

    $i = 1;
    foreach( $key as $s => $e ){
        $i++;
        if( is_array( $e ) ){
            $str .= implode(",",$e);
        }
        if( count($key) < $i ){

        }else{
            $str .= "|";
        }   

    }
    echo $str;
}

function get_the_key_of_uname( $name, $players ){
    foreach( $players as $id => $player ){
        $key = array_search( $name, $player );
        if( $key !== false ){
            $e = $id;
            break;
        }       
    }
    unset( $players[$id] );
    return $players;
}

remove_the_name( "Scoop", "Jennifer,2016-02-14 10:41:02|Don,2016-02-14 11:41:02|Scoop,2016-02-14 10:41:02|" );
?>
```

I wrote this full function, this will be easy for you. :)

Comment: Wow! Will check this out!

Comment: @Emac Tell me it works or not.! I did my testing, it worked perfectly.!

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to incorporate this function into the example I did above.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Emac check you email.

Comment: Hey I checked my email, didn't find anything from you.  I also went to your website about hiring you to assist with some other stuff. Also added you on skype. Please be aware tho that our time zones are different, as I live in the Bahamas, which is now 4:48 PM