# Don't get last occurrence of string in 'replace'

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Found lots of questions about *"How to GET the last occurrence of a string"* but none about **"how to DON'T get it"**, and this is my problem.

I'm working with emojis and I want to count each emoji (`<img>`) of the string **as one char**, so I can get the right length of the string.

When replacing, it finds the beginning (`<img`), but the last part (`>`) is being caught at the last occurrence, not the first one, which closes the first `<img` tag.

This is my code (without unnecessary stuff):

```
 var typed = $(this).html();

 var matches = typed.match(/\<img.*:"\>/g);
 if (matches != null) {
   for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
     console.log('Match ' + i + ': ' + matches[i]);
   }
 }
```

The log result is this:

```
Match 0: <img src="/platform/resources/plugins/emoji-area/img/joy.png" class="img" alt=":joy:"><img src="/platform/resources/plugins/emoji-area/img/evil.gif" class="img" alt=":evil:"><img src="/platform/resources/plugins/emoji-area/img/evil.gif" class="img" alt=":evil:">
```

But it should be:

```
Match 0: <img src="/platform/resources/plugins/emoji-area/img/joy.png" class="img" alt=":joy:">
Match 1: <img src="/platform/resources/plugins/emoji-area/img/evil.gif" class="img" alt=":evil:">
Match 2: <img src="/platform/resources/plugins/emoji-area/img/evil.gif" class="img" alt=":evil:">
```

How do I fix it to get each `<img>` separated?

Comment: Use [non-greedy repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: Use a `DOM` parser instead and loop over the results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy

Comment: And of course, don't forget [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1048572)! What you really want is the [endswith attribute DOM selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/): `$(this).find('img[alt$=":"]')`

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice site Bergi. I can't select the element because I need it as it is, I just need to remove it from the string, but I want it to stay the same, so I can use it elsewhere in the page. Thanks again