# In regexps, what does such an expression mean: .*?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen such an JS regexp: `/hover_cursor\s(.*?);/i`

And am trying to find out why apparently this regexp doesn't match this string (it should match): `"hover_cursor pointer;"`

```
var string = '"hover_cursor pointer;"';
var notetag = '/hover_cursor\s(.*?);/i'
a = string.match(notetag);
writeln(String(a)); // null
```

The one part I don't understand in this regexp is this one: `(.*?)`

Except for this `(.*?)` everything should match: the string `hover_cursor` in the beginning: check. `\s` whitespace: check. Semicolon in the end: check.

So I'm assuming that the problem lies in this `(.*?)`

What does this even mean? Any non-whitespace character (`.`) in any quantity (`.*`) repeated zero or one time?? This question mark seems superflous to me since `*` allows zero repetitions anyway??

Comment: `notetag` is not a `RegExp` instance, it is a string. Remove the single quotes from around it and everything works just fine.

Comment: As I consider this to be a simple typographical error [I'm voting to close it as off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's a non-greedy match. Notice your regex ends with a semicolon. Without the question mark the regex wouldn't stop at the first semicolon it finds, but the last one. Check this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy

Comment: @zzzzBov Thank you. First, this is not a typographical error, but a result of me having to do something in a language I do not know (JS). I assumed regexps should be stored as strings, and I assumed wrongly. I didn't think `/hover_cursor\s(.*?);/i` can be a regex literal. Then, the question about the meaning of the `(.*?)` remains.

Comment: @gaazkam then please update your question to reflect the actual state of the code, but [be sure to have taken the time to do research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418) as asking about what `(.*?)` does can be easily answered by reading the docs on regular expressions.

Comment: Just use a **regex literal**: `var notetag = /hover_cursor\s(.*?);/i`. And read what `.*?` means [here](https://regex101.com/r/Op7lFE/1).