# Regex - get first occurrence

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

> EN=sdfsdf, CN=User Name, CN=Users, DC=domain, DC=co, DC=il

I need to return the first string that starts with "CN=" and ends with an ",".
In this case I need to return "User Name".

'CN=.*,' 
returns 
"CN=User Name, CN=Users, DC=domain, DC=co,"

How can I get the just the first occurrence?

Comment: Like this: `\bCN=[^,]*`

Comment: that also gives 2 matches...

Comment: Don't use the global flag `g`. Depending on your programming language, you may need to use the regex matching function that only matches once (i.e. PHP's `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the non-greedy option in your Regex:

```
CN=.*?,
```

See also [How can I write a regex which matches non greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy)

Comment: that gives 2 matches...