# What does |.*/|| do in Perl regex substitution?

Tags: regex, perl, replace, path, substitution

I'm working on converting Perl cgi script to Python.

Inside the script, I'm came across this below code which I didn't understand.

Help me figure this out.

```
my $p = $0;
$p =~ s|.*/||;
```

I understood that `my $p = $0;` assigns the absolute path+name of the script file to variable **p**.

and the second line is going to perform regex substitution and give only the file name without path.

But what I didn't understand are those `|.*/||` after `s`.

I searched many resources but didn't understand what it does.

What are those things actually going to do to give me only the script name?

Comment: `|`s are delimiters for `s` (substitution) and `.*/` means anything up to last `/`. It replaces it with nothing.

Comment: ok ok. Now I got it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl substitution operator looks like this:

```
s/PATTERN/STRING/
```

But it's also one of those Perl operators that let you choose your own delimiters. So another way to write that is:

```
s|PATTERN|STRING|
```

And that's the version that you're seeing here. Your pattern is `.*/` and the replacement string is empty. So your substitution means "find as many (non-newline) characters as possible that are followed by a slash and replace them with nothing". Looking at that alongside the assignment in the line above it (which uses `$0` - the path of the program) it looks like we have code that removes the directories from the front of a path and just leaves the filename.

That is, if you start with a program name of `/usr/local/bin/my_program`, then `$p` will end up just containing `my_program`.

The better way to write that in Perl is to use the [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) module. I'd be astonished if Python didn't have something similar.

```
use File::Basename;

my $p = basename($0);
```

Comment: A side comment for the fine answer -- `$0` won't give the path but it rather "[_Contains the name of the program_](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$0)."  (At least, it's not guaranteed to give the path.)  The problem with it is (I think) that it doesn't guarantee to return only the name either :)  There's also `FindBin::$RealScript`. One of ways in Python is `os.path.basename(__file__)`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the special variable `$0` does not contain line feeds - the `s|.*/||` regexp actually removes `.*` (everything) before the last (and including last) `/` from your string. So you can cut the path and keep only the filename (everything **after** the last `/`).

There are different delimiters for substitution. It can be `s///` or whatever. Anyway you need to read about the [perl substitution](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch09_06.htm).

FYI.
Also keep in mind, that `.*?` means [non-greedy regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy). So it will match anything before the first `/`.

Comment: @z0lupka `$0` can be set to anything (and thus, `__FILE__` may be a better choice for certain cases but the use case in the OP is unclear). `perl -E'$0 = "foo\nbar"; say $0'`

Comment: @Grinnz., `__FILE__` can be set to anything too via the `#line` pragma

Comment: @ikegami It would require some black magic to do such without being apparent to the code relying on it (also it's far less common and usually used to fix `__LINE__`), whereas `$0` can be globally altered by anything at any time...

Comment: @Grinnz Do you think it makes sense to consider all possible conditions when you write cgi-script with certainly well-defined invocation semantics? And when you are sure that you don't use such obscene pre-defining like '$0 = "foo\nbar";`