# Regex: How to get string as only ordered pattern?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have this string:

```
"You to You know to You have to know Regex more You have to know everything of Regex"
```

I want to get result of pattern: (You) (to) (Regex).
That is:

```
"You to You know to (You) have (to) know (Regex) more (You) have (to) know everything of (Regex)"
```

But my regex gets this:

```
"(You) (to) You know to You have to know (Regex) more (You) have (to) know everything of (Regex)"
```

REGEX: `(You).+?(?=to)(to).+?(?=Regex)(Regex)`

I know my Regex work right as described, but I don't know how to skip First `'You'`.

Thanks.

Comment: `But my regex` Which is? Not sure what you're doing, are those named groups or what?

Comment: Updated with my regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy

Comment: JavaScript? C#? Java?

Comment: @JohnyL, just Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for:

```
(?i)(you)(?:(?!you).)*(to)(?:(?!to).)*(regex)
```

The explanation and Demonstration can be found [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/c8mBda/1).

Comment: Thanks, but instead of "Skpping first occurrence", I want just neighbor-linked pattern. I updated string again. "You to You know to You have to know Regex more You have to know everything of Regex"

Comment: @Luis I am not skipping the first one. Check again. Try using the regex I gave you on your new example. It still captures what you want. It is the logic. I am not skipping anything. The logic is that you should be followed with to and then Regex. That is the logic I used for the regex

Comment: Yes, your answer is best!