# How can I get multiple regex matches using a single parameter?

Tags: php, regex

I want to use RegEx to extract the time that follows after the text "Received:by", but it has many values, and I want to store many values in one parameter.

I've created a RegEx like so:

```
Received:by.+(?P<Hop_Time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)
```

but I got only the last value of `Hop_time`.

This is example of the kind of text that I want to extract `Hop_time` from:

```
Received:by mail-ed1-f69.google.com with SMTP id b21so4825939edt.18          for <budsarin.temsawat@aaa.co.th>; Wed  26 Jun 2019 18:04:32 -0700 (PDT) X-Google-DKIM-Signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;          d=1e100.net; s=20161025;          h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date           :message-id:subject:to:cc;          bh=q04dTGosad+dTkX0DLE3TZT1LvNQX45YXfBh9AMeFco=;          b=a5lzAB+U25QwdRDIw/0H1CT0SGRZNRyiTRNJ1jg5kgfg4IPhyOeWkqm72Ay           w1VV8x3kVzv2jgAyF9/W57NcN43CyejW+ag086fJy2LmqMM03q/Voz7A89av           nxsiIx0V5BOWkcSl3XdBOqQD9imxNL9Bermp548jum51kOopBX6uALrW+Yy           qfSravlh8ONQ8YTOC47iSPBQhCh0b1lMO51p5e6zeIwcLUO62YYl/N3DUKDeN           vduYOj/HAEVQXqfO64Fepx6U2QAi2Lg6hM2zcdKMgDR/Wdj/QehmFj+Fl           Ptag== X-Gm-Message-State:APjAAAUcvfjYPCkT4REkr2t4IE6NeIZTGRWloRcKwy0gyZHb   MynBUQciUYH9gQifGU0TaLv4ddVqHoFhsAXIsniMfUuXeetryhOwO+1bS26ze2SA   fvZIq6qEaOgJlMJZt9nUOMYE2WspxuBWVosL2kKutE99i5q9VzsMDuK+2wlVL4y   MZOpqMIpA6mfKRnzX1cwrcvA9PPbiWI/x7Ldg0kx+kCRuuJQ== X-Received:by 2002:a17:906:3ed1:: with SMTP id d17mr602603ejj.285.1561597403255;          Wed  26 Jun 2019 18:03:23 -0700 (PDT) X-Google-Smtp-Source:APXvYqw4u4lwcGK+asj4XNave7dmVhuneOG1zr46FOmbsgkj0gup9KvdYrzB1LJXS2zMNXf+I= X-Received:by 2002:a17:906:3ed1:: with SMTP id d17mr602584ejj.285.1561597403013;   Wed  26 Jun 2019 18:03:23 -0700 (PDT) MIME-Version:1.0 References:<CAB-UEWaNHyJz4EyotLZA@mail.gmail.com>   <CAB-UEWavdVz0J+ySP5u_GGZm+DVRg@mail.gmail.com>   <CANAFqSiHpjuU5VNQ57MSwc9FuGfwMEu49EvSQ@mail.gmail.com>   <CAB-UEWZBhEzT2QxwsBk-XBfzf7j0qHr5O7tyUxwQw@mail.gmail.com> <CANAFqSiKEMRGkFsA2awnVg5zKSmih6iGOAv7Ng@mail.gmail.com> In-Reply-To:<CANAFqSiKEMRGkFsA2=4wnVg5zKSmih6iGOAv7Ng@mail.gmail.com> From:Sirisri Jitvatkun <sirisri.jitvatkun@bbb.co.th> Date:Thu  27 Jun 2019 08:03:11 +0700
```

From this example text, I want to store three values of `Hop_time`: `"18:04:32"`, `"18:03:23"`, `"18:03:23"`.

Can I do this with RegEx? If so, how should I modify my existing attempt to make it work?

Comment: How are you using the regexp? What language are you using? PHP has `preg_match_all()` to find all matches, Python has `re.findall()`.

Comment: Please add a language tag and show the code.

Comment: @Barmar I'm testing on "https://regex101.com/" with </> PCRE (PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier so that `.+` won't go across multiple occurrences of the pattern.

```
Received:by.+?(?P<Hop_Time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ffhdAb/1)

[How can I write a regex which matches non greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy)

Answer (score 0):

This expression might also work:

```
Received\s*:\s*by.*?(?P<Hop_Time>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})
```

which is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GIFT4R/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/GIFT4R/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

#### Test

```
$re = '/Received\s*:\s*by.*?(?P<Hop_Time>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/s';
$str = 'Received:by mail-ed1-f69.google.com with SMTP id b21so4825939edt.18          for <budsarin.temsawat@aaa.co.th>; Wed  26 Jun 2019 18:04:32 -0700 (PDT) X-Google-DKIM-Signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;          d=1e100.net; s=20161025;          h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date           :message-id:subject:to:cc;          bh=q04dTGosad+dTkX0DLE3TZT1LvNQX45YXfBh9AMeFco=;          b=a5lzAB+U25QwdRDIw/0H1CT0SGRZNRyiTRNJ1jg5kgfg4IPhyOeWkqm72Ay           w1VV8x3kVzv2jgAyF9/W57NcN43CyejW+ag086fJy2LmqMM03q/Voz7A89av           nxsiIx0V5BOWkcSl3XdBOqQD9imxNL9Bermp548jum51kOopBX6uALrW+Yy           qfSravlh8ONQ8YTOC47iSPBQhCh0b1lMO51p5e6zeIwcLUO62YYl/N3DUKDeN           vduYOj/HAEVQXqfO64Fepx6U2QAi2Lg6hM2zcdKMgDR/Wdj/QehmFj+Fl           Ptag== X-Gm-Message-State:APjAAAUcvfjYPCkT4REkr2t4IE6NeIZTGRWloRcKwy0gyZHb   MynBUQciUYH9gQifGU0TaLv4ddVqHoFhsAXIsniMfUuXeetryhOwO+1bS26ze2SA   fvZIq6qEaOgJlMJZt9nUOMYE2WspxuBWVosL2kKutE99i5q9VzsMDuK+2wlVL4y   MZOpqMIpA6mfKRnzX1cwrcvA9PPbiWI/x7Ldg0kx+kCRuuJQ== X-Received:by 2002:a17:906:3ed1:: with SMTP id d17mr602603ejj.285.1561597403255;          Wed  26 Jun 2019 18:03:23 -0700 (PDT) X-Google-Smtp-Source:APXvYqw4u4lwcGK+asj4XNave7dmVhuneOG1zr46FOmbsgkj0gup9KvdYrzB1LJXS2zMNXf+I= X-Received:by 2002:a17:906:3ed1:: with SMTP id d17mr602584ejj.285.1561597403013;   Wed  26 Jun 2019 18:03:23 -0700 (PDT) MIME-Version:1.0 References:<CAB-UEWaNHyJz4EyotLZA@mail.gmail.com>   <CAB-UEWavdVz0J+ySP5u_GGZm+DVRg@mail.gmail.com>   <CANAFqSiHpjuU5VNQ57MSwc9FuGfwMEu49EvSQ@mail.gmail.com>   <CAB-UEWZBhEzT2QxwsBk-XBfzf7j0qHr5O7tyUxwQw@mail.gmail.com> <CANAFqSiKEMRGkFsA2awnVg5zKSmih6iGOAv7Ng@mail.gmail.com> In-Reply-To:<CANAFqSiKEMRGkFsA2=4wnVg5zKSmih6iGOAv7Ng@mail.gmail.com> From:Sirisri Jitvatkun <sirisri.jitvatkun@bbb.co.th> Date:Thu  27 Jun 2019 08:03:11 +0700
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```