# Python Regex - grab a block of whitespace from end of string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex that grabs blocks of whitespace from either side of a string. I can get the beginning, but I can't seem to grab the end block.

```
s = '     This is a string with whitespace on either side     '

strip_regex = re.compile(r'(\s+)(.*)(something to grab end block)')
mo = strip_regex.findall(s)
```

What I get as an output is this:

```
[('        ', 'This is a string with whitespace on either side        ')]
```

I have played around with that to do at the end, and the best I can get is one whitespace but I can never just grab the string until the end of 'side'. I don't want to use the characters in side because I want the regex to work with any string surrounded by whitespace. I am pretty sure that it's because I am using the (.*) which is just grabbing everything after the first whitespace block. But can't figure out how to make it stop before the end whitespace block.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is strip whitespace, you could use strip() instead.
See: https://www.journaldev.com/23625/python-trim-string-rstrip-lstrip-strip

As for your regex, if you want both the start and end whitespace, I suggest matching the whole line, with the middle part not greedy like so:

```
s = '     This is a string with whitespace on either side     '
strip_regex = re.compile(r'^(\s+)(.*?)(\s+)$')
mo = strip_regex.findall(s)
```

Result:

```
[('     ', 'This is a string with whitespace on either side', '     ')]
```

More about greedy: [How can I write a regex which matches non greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy)

Comment: That's awesome thank you! Literally just had to move the $ outside of the last group and it would have worked! I was trying to write a regex which would imitate the strip() function :)