# Match returns another outpu

Tags: ruby

after inserting input value "https://youtu.be/KMBBjzp5hdc" the code returns output value "https://youtu.be/"

```
str = gets.chomp.to_s
puts /.*[=\/]/.match(str)
```

I do not understand why as i would expect https:/

Thanks for advise!

Comment: Can add input and output to the question instead of the links?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write a regex which matches non greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy)

Comment: Short answer: `/.*?[=\/]/.match str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] the code returns output value `"https://youtu.be/"` [...] I do not understand why as i would expect `https:/`

Your regexp `/.*[=\/]/` matches:

- `.*` zero or more characters
- `[=\/]` followed by a `=` or `/` character

In your example string, there are 3 candidates that end with a `/` character: (and none ending with `=`)

1. `https:/`
2. `https://`
3. `https://youtu.be/`

[Repetition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Repetition) like `*` is *greedy* by default, i.e. it matches as many characters as it can. From the 3 options above, it matches the *longest* one which is `https://youtu.be/`.

You can append a `?` to make the repetition *lazy*, which results in the shortest match:

```
"https://youtu.be/KMBBjzp5hdc".match(/.*?[=\/]/)
#=> #<MatchData "https:/">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "https://youtu.be/KMBBjzp5hdc"
matches = str.match(/(https:\/\/youtu.be\/)(.+)/)
matches[1]
```

Outputs:

```
"https://youtu.be/"
```