# Regexp: Give specific end higher priority than in character list

Tags: python, regex

Test string has four  classes, all on one row, that's why I can't use '.' for any match. This means I have to use a character list. Working example where everything is fine here. Span 1, 2, and 4 get correctly matched. Link: https://regex101.com/r/QpHJNw/1

However let's assume the first character list has to gets extended to [\w\d\s"=<>:./] because for some reason the test string will contain such data, regardless if its html conform:

New regexp:

```
<span class=\"select\"[\w\d\s\"=<>:./]*><a href=[\w\d\s\"<>:/.-]+</a></span>
```

New test string:

```
<span class="select" foo="1<>/"><a href="https://www.domain.tld">Word 1</a></span><span class="select"><a href="https://www.domain.tld">Word 2</a></span><span class="no_select"><a href="https://www.domain.tld">Word 3</a></span><span class="select" bar="2"><a href="https://www.domain.tld">Word 4</a></span>
```

Link: https://regex101.com/r/6S37B3/1

This matches naturally the entire string as the character list contains all the used signs. Is there a way to give the ending `</a></span>` of the regpex a higher priority, meaning regardless what's in the character list, do *always* match the first occurrence of it. In the end it should do the same matching as in the first example, span 1, 2, and 4.

Thanks!

Comment: If the data you expect will contain invalid html, how can you be sure that the invalid text it contains doesn't also contain `</a></span>` where you don't want to match it?

Comment: As for a solution to your problem, adding a `?` right after the `*` seems like a straightforward one? (i.e. you don't want `*` to be greedy here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [non greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy) regex by adding `?` to `*` and `+`:

`<span class=\"select\"[\w\d\s\"=<>:./]*?><a href=[\w\d\s\"<>:/.-]+?</a></span>`

P.S. Don't parse HTML with regexp, think about bs4/html.parser/lxml