# Getting a word after a word match in regex

Tags: regex

I want to get two specific words using regex after a word

So I have the following text

```
code: 'dev-foo-1', text: foo, bla:, blabla, ..., tokenId: '1234566343434', accountId: '123456789',...
```

I want from this text only the code `dev-foo-1` and the account id `123456789`
But I am having problem to select those two.

I tried to do something like

```
code:'\([a-z]{3})([a-z]+)([0-9])'\accountId: \'([0-9])'
```

which it's wrong.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't include the `-` characters in the word after `code`.

Comment: Why do you have `\a` in the regexp?

Comment: Space missing, `+` missing... Not pattern with `-` ...

Comment: The regexp needs `.*` before `accountId`. And you need a space after `code:`

Comment: These are all obvious differences between your text and the regexp.

Comment: What regexp flavor are you using? In most RE, `\(` matches a literal `(`, it's not used to start a capture group. And if it's used for a capture group, you have to match it with `\)`.

Comment: `\'([0-9])'` should have the backslash before `(`, not `'`.

Comment: Almost made work by doing ``code: '([a-z]{3})-([a-z]+)-([0-9])'.*accountId: ([0-9]{12})`` The code part is working like I want but not getting the account id

Comment: There are not 12 digits, but 9 https://regex101.com/r/Gdb1as/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note that I've ignored backslashes in your code because they appear to be inconsistently applied – you'll need to add slashes before each single-quote if you're using single-quoted strings to delimit your patterns)

If `code` always appears before `accountId` then you're pretty close to an answer. You're missing a space between `code` and the code, and also the dashes between the sections of the code:

```
code: '([a-z]{3}-[a-z]+-[0-9])'
```

There can then be any characters at all before the `accountId`, so you'll need `.*` to match them. Actually, you can use `.*?` to be [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy).

Finally, your `accountId` currently matches only a single digit, but you'll presumably want to match one *or more* with `[0-9]+`:

```
code: '([a-z]{3}-[a-z]+-[0-9])'.*?accountId: '([0-9]+)'
```

... and we are done.